# How to get event that the user started to drag a file in SwiftUI/Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

**Background**

In SwiftUI (Swift 5) I want to be able to receive an event whenever a user starts dragging a *file* outside of my app (macos, 12+). My app won't show a window until the user starts dragging a file, then I want to show a window (view) and let the user drag that file there.

**Current Progress**

I have tried different ways to get an event among which are:

1. Using an `NSView` which registers drag support using `registerForDraggedTypes` and by overriding `draggingEntered()` -> This works, but only when the the file is dragged over the view. I don't receive the event as soon as the user starts dragging the file from finder
2. Using `.onDrag()` on the SwiftUI view which has the same issue as before. Only works when the mouse is over the view.
3. Using `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDragged]) ...)` -> With this, I am able to get the desired event. But I get this event also for moving a window. I only want to get this event when the user is actually dragging a file from anywhere (Finder, Desktop, ...)

**Questions**

1. How can I get an event whenever a user starts to dragging a file from anywhere (without my app being in foreground or showing any window)
2. `NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.leftMouseDragged]) ...)` seems quite promising. Is there a way to figure out that the user is actually dragging a file right now? (not a window...)